# Is RawOptionSetType compatible Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I recently discovered the way to create `NS_OPTIONS` equivalent in Swift, however I cannot use them from Objective-C code in a Objective-C/Swift project.

Here is a sample project I did:

*ObjcObject.h & ObjcObject.m*

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, MyObjcOption)
{
    MyOptionNone = 0,
    MyObjcOptionCase01  = 1 << 0,
    MyObjcOptionCase02  = 1 << 1,
    MyObjcOptionCaseAll = MyObjcOptionCase01 | MyObjcOptionCase02
};

@interface ObjcObject : NSObject

+ (void)printMyObjcOption:(MyObjcOption)option;

@end

@implementation ObjcObject

+ (void)printMyObjcOption:(MyObjcOption)option
{
    if (option == 0)
        NSLog(@"None");

    if (option & MyObjcOptionCase01)
        NSLog(@"MyObjcOptionCase01");

    if (option & MyObjcOptionCase02)
        NSLog(@"MyObjcOptionCase02");
}

@end
```

*SwiftObject.swift*

```
struct MySwiftOption: RawOptionSetType, BooleanType {
    private var value: UInt = 0
    var rawValue: UInt { return self.value }

    init(_ value: UInt)         { self.value = value }
    init(rawValue value: UInt)  { self.value = value }
    init(nilLiteral: ())        { self.value = 0 }

    var boolValue: Bool { return value != 0 }

    static var allZeros: MySwiftOption  { return self(0) }
    static var None: MySwiftOption      { return self(0) }
    static var All: MySwiftOption       { return self.Case01 | self.Case02 }

    static var Case01: MySwiftOption    { return self(1 << 0) }
    static var Case02: MySwiftOption    { return self(1 << 1) }
}

public class SwiftObject: NSObject {
    class func printMySwiftOption(option: MySwiftOption) {
        if option.rawValue == 0 {
            println("None")
        }

        if option & MySwiftOption.Case01 {
            println(".Case01")
        }

        if option & MySwiftOption.Case02 {
            println(".Case02")
        }
    }

    class func sayHello() {
        println("Hello")
    }
}
```

*AppDelegate.m*

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    MyObjcOption objcOption = MyObjcOptionCase02;
    [ObjcObject printMyObjcOption:objcOption];

    [SwiftObject sayHello];
//    MySwiftOption swiftOption = MySwiftOptionCase02; // Error: Use of undeclared identifier 'MySwiftOption'
//    [SwiftObject printMySwiftOption:swiftOption];

    return YES;
}
```

In the Objective-C code, I always get an error `Use of undeclared identifier 'MySwiftOption'`.

Is it a known issue? Is there a workaround?

Comment: did you add the bridging header file?

Comment: Need I? I think I don't need it: I do not import Objective-C into Swift. However I imported the `*-Swift.h` file. `[SwiftObject sayHello];` works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expose structs from Swift to ObjectiveC. Actually, have a look at the -Swift.h file to see what you can access from Objective. You won't find MySwiftOptions in there.

> You’ll have access to anything within a class or protocol that’s
>   marked with the @objc attribute as long as it’s compatible with
>   Objective-C. This excludes Swift-only features such as those listed
>   here:
>
> Generics Tuples,
>
> Enumerations defined in Swift,
>
> Structures defined in Swift,
>
> Top-level functions defined in Swift,
>
> Global variables defined in Swift,
>
> Typealiases defined in Swift,
>
> Swift-style variadics Nested types,
>
> Curried functions

I, for one, am living with these limitations on a daily bases.

[Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C at Apple.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_86)

Comment: Crap, I forgot it! It makes sense. Thanks for the remember!